# Utilisation et épellation de "tout autre"

Tags: anglais, homonymes

J'essaie de traduire une phrase de l'anglais,

> Any other slips

Dans le contexte, le mot français pour `slip` est `feuillet`. La traduction que j'aimerais utiliser est

> Tout autres feuillets

Malheureusement je suis incapable de déterminer si ceci est grammaticalement correct. En particulier, si le sujet devrait être au pluriel en français, et si j'utilise la bonne forme et le bon accord pout "tout". Pouvez vous m'éclairer?

Merci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D’après ce que je vois dans le [Grevisse](http://www.lebonusage.com/), dans l'expression "tout autre" en général, “tout” est immuable, mais “autre” s’accorde en nombre. Dans votre cas, cela donnerait effectivement:

> Tout autres feuillets